# Pandas - Populate an empty column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through some dataframe values, and populate an empty column as I do it, like so:

```
df_team_matches['Result'] = ""
results = []

for row in df_team_matches.itertuples():
    goals = row.Goals
    conceded = row.GoalsConceded
    if goals > conceded:
        result = 'win'
        results.append(result)
    elif goals < conceded:
        result = 'defeat'
        results.append(result)
    elif goals == conceded:
        result = 'draw'
        results.append(result)
    
df_team_matches['Result'] = results
```

The above works, but it seems to my a bit cumbersome.

Is there a cleaner, faster way of achieving the same result using some `pandas` method?

Comment: AH, scratch that, you probably want ["conditional column creation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column/19913845)

Comment: sorry, I meant populate an empty column, have edited the question.

Comment: Check my edited comment please?

Comment: did it. thank you!